# How to get outbound call sid that is created with StartOutboundCall from Flex

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-flex

I'm making outbound calls through Twilio Flex with `StartOutboundCall` built-in action. I want to be able to manage call recording during and after the call so that I can start-stop-delete recording when necessary. However, I am not able to get call sid to do so. Is there an easy way to get call sid for a call that is started by `StartOutboundCall`?

- `StartOutboundCall` some info: https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/voice/dialpad-click-to-dial#the-outbound-call-action-1
- So far I was able to find a conference object within task attributes when I listen to "AcceptTask" event and look at its payload object, but it's not always there. Maybe the insertion of that property happens asynchronously and I should get it after a certain event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with Flex events and some support from Twilio, I found an object `conference` is being added as a task attribute after the event `afterAcceptTask`.

The `conference` object contains both agent's and customer's call sid. You can use the agent's call sid, which is under `task.attributes.conference.participants.worker`, to manage the call recording or other resources that require a call sid.

Note: I wasn't able to get this `conference` object consistently in the `afterAcceptTask` listener, so I made sure that I accessed the object after this event. This way I consistently hit the object and was able to get and use the call sid successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After dealing with a similar issue, Twilio support instructed me to use the worker as CallerSid, which works perfectly.

The trick is to use this event because it is the moment the call have being created/connected/accepted, and the worker is available as CallerSid.

```
Twilio.Flex.Manager.getInstance()
  .workerClient.on('reservationCreated', 
     (reservation) => {
        reservation.on('accepted', (accepted) => {
            console.log("!!!!Reservation", accepted.task.attributes.conference.participants.worker);
        });
    });
```

afterTaskAccepted action listener DOES NOT properly work for outbound calls.